# Getting json file fields issue

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

OK, I am new to python but what I am trying to do is to access  specific fields from a json text file 
my json text file is like this:

```
{
 "paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=5000&offset=5000&type=page&q=%26&locale=ar_AR&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAD7z1vK0aO2Mlb1QZBOb9OwjYZCZBZB56P0MrYnt54WJYZCZBy4ZBv4zaYG0mj9ZCZAMkZBmlP83E885ykZAafog7QbcWwEtvRXfjtVa12DBnW8omWsnC8N6lsmNK7yktI89kBDdrTH9TOIdATHdsX5OewWhzGTpXDelSjE8HAbtcn08zSWsweDc4UZD&__after_id=139433456868"
 }, 
 "data": [
  {
   "category": "\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645", 
   "name": "The London School of Economics and Political Science - LSE", 
   "category_list": [
    {
     "id": "108051929285833", 
     "name": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0629"
    }, 
    {
     "id": "187751327923426", 
     "name": "\u0645\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0629"
    }
   ], 
   "id": "6127898346"
  },
```

the filed that I want to access is the 'category_list' filed in order to get the 'id' filed
I have tried some thing like this:

```
import json
idvalue = []
jsonFile = open('samples0.txt', 'r')
values = json.load(jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
idValue = values['data'][0]['category_list'][0]['id']
print idvalue
```

but it keeps telling me that there is a key error.
what I am missing here?
what is the wrong thing I am doing?
any help please

edit : 
my code returning null I still cannot understand why?

Comment: s/print idvalue/print idValue/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`values['data'][0]['category_list']` is a list, so something like `values['data'][0]['category_list'][0]['id']` should work.

Comment: is it 2 dim array ? how to declare it?

Comment: if I declare it as idvalue = [] it keeps returning null

Comment: Change `print idvalue` to `print idValue`

Answer (score 2):

No need to declare `idValue`. Just use it as

```
idValue = values['data'][0]['category_list'][0]['id']
```